# Handling empty strings, nulls, and undefined values in filter pipe [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I am writing a pipe to filter values in an array of objects.  I have the foundations implemented, but I am having trouble handling empty strings, nulls, and undefined values.  Whenever one of these values is passed to the pipe, all the values from the array should be returned.  The pipe has the ability to filter on an object's property, as well as filtering on an array of primitive string or numeric values.  I have some test cases that I have written.  All of them are passing except for the ones dealing with the title of this post.

**property-filter.pipe.ts**

```
export class PropertyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], args: any[] | any): any[] {
    const filterProperty = args[1]; // property to filter on
    const minVal = args[0] || args; // input from user to filter
    return value.filter((item: any) => {
      if (item[filterProperty] && minVal !== ('' || undefined || null))
        return item[filterProperty].toString().includes(minVal);
      else if (minVal === ('' || undefined || null)) // where I'm trying to handle the "empty" cases
        return (item[filterProperty].toString().includes(item) || item.toString().includes(item));
      else return item.toString().includes(minVal);
    });
  }

}
```

**failing test case**

```
it('should return a list of all matches if the user has not given any input', function () {
    const icas = [
      {ica: '123'},
      {ica: '456'},
      {ica: '789'},
      {ica: '1234'}
    ];
    const filterProp = 'ica';
    const nums = [123, 456, 789];
    let result = pipe.transform(icas, ['', filterProp]);
    expect(result).toEqual(icas);
    result = pipe.transform(icas, [null, filterProp]);
    expect(result).toEqual(icas);
    result = pipe.transform(icas, [undefined, filterProp]);
    expect(result).toEqual(icas);
    result = pipe.transform(nums, '');
    expect(result).toEqual([123, 456, 789]);
    result = pipe.transform(nums, null);
    expect(result).toEqual([123, 456, 789]);
    result = pipe.transform(nums, undefined);
    expect(result).toEqual([123, 456, 789]);
  });
```

The result of the `expect` statement in the test case is an empty array, where it should be returning an array of all the values (i.e. `icas` or `nums`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem that your test is wrong, but your implementation is.

The condition on the right side of your `else if` statement always evaluates to false. So you're actually checking `minVal === false` which is never the case.

Changing this to `else if (!minVal) { ... }` should be sufficient.

edit: same goes for the first condition, it should be `if (item[filterProperty] && minVal)` instead.

Comment: That makes sense.  So, null, empty string, and undefined are falsy values in JavaScript and should never be used in a conditional?

Comment: Also, do you think it'd be better to split this pipe into two pipes?  One for filtering on an object's property, and one just for filtering on an array of primitive numeric/string values?

Comment: @brianthomps never is a strong word ;) There are cases you might want to check against `null` for example. In most cases you just want to know if a value is set and has a length, therefore a simple `!minVal` in your case is just enough. To answer your second question, i think that's personal opinion. I would probably not do it with a pipe anyway, but if i would split them just for maintainability reasons.